# import parentheses from another package but original hat and bar can't display correctly

Tags: declare

I use
`\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

but import '"(" & ")" from package `stix` instead.

code as follows

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{"2E}{largesymbolsstix}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"2F}{largesymbolsstix}{"01}
```

This replacement is working but when I input `\hat{X}` or `\bar{X}`, they can't display correctly, see below

[image]

Any idea to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: please show a small but complete document that produces the output shown

Answer (score 1):

The code is very incomplete, as it doesn't show how `largesymbolsstix` is defined.

However, it's sufficient to see why your code fails. You're replacing the `operators` math font, where most math accents are taken from, with a font that hasn't them.

Change the instances of `{operators}` to `{parenthesesstix}` or whatever string you prefer.

Comment: solved and thank you so much